# How to programmatically get Kafka Cluster and Broker information in Java?

Tags: java, spring-boot, apache-kafka, spring-kafka

I wish to get all active brokers on my kafka cluster programmatically from the worker itself.
The idea is to create a health scheduler that will check and return the active brokers address.

In each worker, I set up the cluster address when I set up the consumer configuration

```
props.put(onsumerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, myServerAddress);
```

However, this will not tell me which brokers are active at the moment.

I did some searching, but I could not find any way of getting this info. Is it possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can retrieve all details of Kafka brokers in a cluster using [`describeCluster()`](https://kafka.apache.org/20/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/clients/admin/AdminClient.html#describeCluster-org.apache.kafka.clients.admin.DescribeClusterOptions-) of `AdminClient`:

> Get information about the nodes in the cluster.
>
> Parameters: options - The options to use when getting information
>   about the cluster.
>
> Returns: The  `DescribeClusterResult`.

```
// Create AdminClient
Properties props = new Properties();
props.load(new FileInputStream("ac.properties"));
AdminClient adminClient = KafkaAdminClient.create(props);

// Get brokers' details 
DescribeClusterResult describeClusterResult = adminClient.describeCluster();
List<Node> brokers = new ArrayList<>(describeClusterResult.nodes().get());
for (Node broker : brokers) {
    System.out.println("Host=" + broker.host() + ", Port=" + broker.port());
}
```